# Vectorial $L^p$ spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vectors, lp-spaces, stokes-theorem, holder-inequality

Consider the space

$$Ł^p(\Omega):=(L^p(\Omega))^N=L^p(\Omega)×L^p(\Omega)×...×L^p(\Omega), \, N \ge 1,\, \Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n},$$

as the vectorial $L^p$ space associated to the scalar one.

**My questions are:**

1. What is the norm $||\cdot||_{Ł^p}$ and can we relate it to $||\cdot||_{L^p}$?
2. How to apply the *Hölder Inequality* on

$$\int_{\Omega}{u(x)\cdot v(x)dx},$$

where

$u \in Ł^q$, $v \in Ł^p$,
$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, $u=(u_1,...,u_N)^t$,
$v=(v_1,....,v_N)^t$,
$u_i \in L^q(\Omega)$, $v_i \in L^p(\Omega)$, and $u(x)\cdot v(x)$ is the scalar product between?

Comment: What do you mean, $(L^p(\Omega))^N$ ? Do you mean the product space $L^p(\Omega) \times ... \times L^p(\Omega)$ ($N$ times) ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes that what I mean

Comment: @TheSilverDoe sorry but do you have an answer? for the relation between these two norms?

Comment: @sara I'd assume that $||u||_{L^{p}(\Omega)^{N}} = \sum_{i=1}^{N}||u_{i}||_{L^{p}(\Omega)}$ where $u_{i}$ is the $i$th component of $u$ viewed as a vector. Then Holders inequality still holds. N.B. By definition this is a norm.

Answer (score 1):

A nice norm is
$$
\lVert u \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)^N} := \sqrt[p]{\sum_{i = 1}^N \lVert u_i \Vert_{L^p(\Omega)}^p}.
$$
If $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^N}$ is *any* norm on $\mathbb{R}^N$, then it is easy to see that  $\lVert u \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)^N}$ is equivalent to
$$
\lVert u \rVert := \lVert (\lVert u_1 \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)}, ...,  \lVert u_N \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)})^\top \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^N}.
$$
In the case of $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)^N}$ we had set $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{\mathbb{R}^N} := \lVert \cdot \rVert_p$.

The Hölder inequality also holds in the following sense: We first use the Hölder-inequality of $\mathbb{R}^N$ inside the integral and then use the Hölder-inequality for Lebesgue-integrals:
$$
\int_\Omega u \cdot v ~\mathrm{d}x \leq \int_\Omega \lVert u \Vert_p \lVert v \Vert_q ~\mathrm{d}x \leq \sqrt[p]{\int_\Omega \lVert u \rVert_p^p ~\mathrm{d}x} \sqrt[q]{\int_\Omega \lVert v \rVert_q^q ~\mathrm{d}x} =
$$
$$
\sqrt[p]{\sum_{i = 1}^N \int_\Omega \lvert u_i \rvert^p~\mathrm{d}x}\sqrt[q]{\sum_{i = 1}^N \int_\Omega \lvert v_i \rvert^q~\mathrm{d}x} = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{i = 1}^N \lVert u_i \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)}^p} \sqrt[q]{\sum_{i = 1}^N \lVert v_i \rVert_{L^q(\Omega)}^q} = 
\lVert u \rVert_{L^p(\Omega)^N} \lVert v \rVert_{L^q(\Omega)^N}
$$